# radio button to work differently on event fire but a radio button need 2 clicks to get checked

Tags: html, angular, web, angular9

In `.html` file:

```
<input type="radio" name="single" id={{list}} value={{list}} 
       [(ngModel)]="ChoiceOptionsList[list-1].isCorrect" #radval="ngModel" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
       (change)="setRadioOption($event)" #radval required/>
```

Note: list consist of increment number like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....

In `.TS` file:

```
setRadioOption(event: any)
{
    for(let i = 0; i < this.singleChoiceOptionsList.length; i++)
    {
         this.ChoiceOptionsList[i].isCorrect=false;

         if((i+1)==event.target.id)
         {
              this.ChoiceOptionsList[i].isCorrect=true;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: share template code.. hard to debug!

Comment: if it is angualr code, why u are doing like this. u can bind event on element

Comment: @Keshav, a radioButton it used to give value to a variable among a serie of choices, so has no sense use different variable in the [(ngModel)] (and you don't need (change) nor [ngModelOptions]

Comment: Thanks @xdeepakv for your help. It really helped my code to run smoothly. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo for your help. It really solved my issue. Thanks –